# Dynamin created link pass object as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created dynamic  `<a />` tag  with a onclick event and this event call a function which contains a object as parameter ,which I passed but onclick on the link an error occurred  **SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script**

```
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<script>

function callconfirm(cb,pmessage)
{
   // var isConfirmed
     BootstrapDialog.confirm({
            title: 'WARNING',
            message: pmessage,
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
            closable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            draggable: false, // <-- Default value is false
            btnCancelLabel: 'Do not drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'Cancel',
            btnOKLabel: 'Drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
            btnOKClass: 'btn-warning', // <-- If you didn't specify it, dialog type will be used,
            callback:cb /*function(result) {
                // result will be true if button was click, while it will be false if users close the dialog directly.
                if(result) {
                  return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            }*/
        });


}


function b1checkConfirm(result,id)
{
    //callconfirm();
    console.log("B1 click and result is "+result);
     console.log(this.p1);
    console.log(this.p2);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.write('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="javascript:callconfirm(b1checkConfirm.bind({p1: Hello, p2:World}),"Hello")" >Click</a>');
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is this part of the document.write:

```
b1checkConfirm.bind({p1: Hello, p2:World}),"Hello"
```

The ***Hello*** and ***World*** must be escaped, and because they are part of the HTML you may write:

```
b1checkConfirm.bind({p1: &apos;Hello&apos;, p2: &apos;World&apos;}),&apos;Hello&apos;
```

The snippet:

```js
function callconfirm(cb,pmessage)
{
    // var isConfirmed
    BootstrapDialog.confirm({
        title: 'WARNING',
        message: pmessage,
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING, // <-- Default value is BootstrapDialog.TYPE_PRIMARY
        closable: false, // <-- Default value is false
        draggable: false, // <-- Default value is false
        btnCancelLabel: 'Do not drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'Cancel',
        btnOKLabel: 'Drop it!', // <-- Default value is 'OK',
        btnOKClass: 'btn-warning', // <-- If you didn't specify it, dialog type will be used,
        callback:cb /*function(result) {
         // result will be true if button was click, while it will be false if users close the dialog directly.
         if(result) {
         return true;
         }else {
         return false;
         }
         }*/
    });


}


function b1checkConfirm(result,id)
{
    //callconfirm();
    console.log("B1 click and result is "+result);
    console.log(this.p1);
    console.log(this.p2);
}

document.write('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="javascript:callconfirm(b1checkConfirm.bind({p1: &apos;Hello&apos;, p2: &apos;World&apos;}),&apos;Hello&apos;)" >Click</a>')
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.7/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `"` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.write('<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="javascript:callconfirm(b1checkConfirm.bind({p1: Hello, p2:World}),\"Hello\")" >Click</a>');
</script>
```

Because the code will think the onClick event finish after the second first `"` of your hello

Comment: You actually need to use `\'` because `document.write` will strip off the `\" ` and the code will be back to the same problem of the `onclick` ending soon.